# Count IF multiple critera in multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm pretty new to excel. I can do basic formulas or research a solution for my problem but this one has me stumped.

I'm trying to count how many tickets were "WIP (work in progress)" for the calendar month. Right now it's counting based on the "Status" is in WIP and if the "Date Received" date range is in-between the calendar month. But I also need to add a condition where if the ticket is in Closed "Status" and if the date range in "Date Responded" is greater than that calendar month. I've tried to write a formula but it's incorrect because it's just returning 0.

I've attached a screenshot of what my spread sheet looks like.

```
=COUNTIFS(Table_query[Status], "=WIP", Table_query[Date Received],">=1/1/2019", Table_query[Date Received], "<=1/31/2019", Table_query[Date Responded], ">=1/31/2019", Table_query[Status], "=CLOSED")
```

[image]

Comment: Try copying the values out of the pivot table. Often pivot table results act funny in formulas.

Comment: It was just a table, but I re-did it with "f2:f1172" etc and still get the same result. I think what my formula is doing is looking if theres CLOSED and WIP in the second column instead of looking for either or. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Countif() only counts an item if every condition returns true (logical "and"). If you want to have an "or", you have to either sum two or more countif()s or use sum(countif(Range,{orCondition_1, orCondition_2, orCondition_i})
2. Excel doesn't automatically understand, that the date string, you are comparing your date columns to, is a date.

Change ">=1/31/2019" to ">="&DATEVALUE("01/31/2019")

(analogous for every date)

Background: Excel acutally stores dates as a number, see [www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time](http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time)

Check if the following fits your logical needs

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(
  Table_query[Status], {"WIP", "Closed"},
  Table_query[Date Received], ">="&datevalue("01/01/2019"), Table_query[Date Received], "<="&datevalue("01/31/2019"),
  Table_query[Date Responded], ">="&datevalue(01/31/2019")))

=SUM(
 COUNTIFS(
  Table_query[Status], "WIP",
  Table_query[Date Received], ">="&DATEVALUE("2/1/2019"), Table_query[Date Received], "<="&DATEVALUE("2/28/2019"))
 ,COUNTIFS(
  Table_query[Status], "Closed",
  Table_query[Date Received], ">="&DATEVALUE("2/1/2019"), Table_query[Date Received], "<="&DATEVALUE("2/28/2019"),
  Table_query[Date Responded], ">"&DATEVALUE("2/28/2019"))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I went ahead and changed the formula to:
`=COUNTIFS(B2:B1172,"=WIP",F2:F1172,">="&DATEVALUE("1/1/2019"),F2:F1172,"<="&DATEVALUE("1/31/2019"),B2:B1172,"=Closed",H2:H1172,">="&DATEVALUE("01/31/2019"))`  but it's still not returning those 2 records (Flextronics and BMW) that were closed AFTER 1/31, and have the status of Closed. It should be counted as a WIP because it wasn't closed within the calendar month

Comment: I didn’t realize the two Status conditions that exclude each other at first , sorry. Replace the two [status] condition pairs with    Table_query[Status], {“WIP”,”CLOSED”}    and wrap the whole countif part in a sum()

Comment: I ended up SUMing two countifs together since there was multiple conditions I needed. I couldn't have done the logic without your help. The final formula I came up with was `=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table_query[Status], "WIP",Table_query[Date Received], ">="&DATEVALUE("2/1/2019"), Table_query[Date Received], "<="&DATEVALUE("2/28/2019")),COUNTIFS(Table_query[Date Received], ">="&DATEVALUE("2/1/2019"), Table_query[Date Received], "<="&DATEVALUE("2/28/2019"), Table_query[Status], "Closed", Table_query[Date Responded], ">"&DATEVALUE("2/28/2019")))` If you add It to your answer, I'll mark it as the answer.